# Necessary to use server language with DataTable JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, datatable

If I am populating a table with data from a database in MVC 5, do I need to use a server language like AJAX to have DataTables work correctly? I've never worked with one before and all of the tutorials seem pretty poor. I'm just looking for some guidance on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, although it is an option, jQuery DataTables does not require that you populate it via an AJAX call. You can simply initialize DataTables on a static HTML table and it will transform it into a grid with pagination and search enabled by default.

There are three possible datasources (two of witch do not require server-side logic)

- DOM (i.e. the plain HTML of the document)
- Javascript
- Ajax sourced data

See the [Data sources](http://www.datatables.net/manual/data) section of the manual